# Mouse zoom is offset in HighStocks when inside frameset

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-10, highcharts, frameset

When running Highstocks 1.2.5 (or the latest 1.3.2) causes problems in IE10 (although works in IE9 or earlier), jQuery 1.6.4. This works if the page is not inside of a frameset, but if hosted inside of a frameset (i.e. frame src="thispagebelow").

ascii art of the hosted frameset, x marks thispagebelow

```
----------
|   t    |
----------
|   |    |
| l | x  |
|   |    |
----------
```

Basically, if my mouse is at X-Coordinate 200, then the tooltip and zoom selection behaves as if it was at 80. I believe that in the example, the left hand frame (i.e. "l") is probably around 120px wide (ie. 80 = 200 - 120).

```
<!doctype html public "-//w3c//dtd html 4.0 transitional//en">
<html>    
  <head><title>in frameset</title>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script><!-- version 1.6.4 -->
    <script src="highstock.js"></script><!-- version 1.2.5 -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    /* first 33 points of highcharts aapl data hardcoded */
    var data = [ [1150243200000,57.61], ... ,[1154304000000,67.96] ];
    new Highcharts.StockChart({
      chart: { renderTo: 'container', type: 'line', zoomType: 'x' },
      series: [{ name: 'AAPL', data: data }]
    });
  });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container" style="width:800px; height: 500px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

IE10's Compatibility View is turned on. (Windows 8)

IE9's Compatibility View is turned on. (Windows 7)

Running Highstocks 1.2.5 we can zoom in the frameset, it is just offset from where it should be.

Running Highstocks 1.3.2 zooming is challenging as the "mouse-up" doesn't want to fire (i.e. we get the selected zoom area, but we never "zoom in" and the highlighted area doesn't change.

Comment: Well, have you encountered that issue on any demos? For example: http://jsfiddle.net/Dmx24/

Comment: Can you show us a live reproduction of this?

Comment: This issue is fixed with https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/2005